# how does one put a background on a floating element in css3 and change it's opacity?

Tags: html, css

In the css I have a few images in the style folder so ignore the other images that don't show up. The floating element leftpara and joinbutton(eventhough it's a para not the button) have background white and i want to give it an opacity of .4.

```
#stuff:before{
  display: block; content:""; position: absolute; z-index:-1;
  background: url(blah.jpg);
  opacity:.3;
  top:10%; left: 0; right: 0; 
  height: 50%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unjzL9xe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

with`hsla(0,0%,100%,0.70)` or rgba you use a white background with whatever percentage saturation or opacity to get the look you desire.
and you can use `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`  to get the opacity

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(blah.jpg);
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,0.70);
background-blend-mode: overlay;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly vague, however the following code applies *"a background on a floating element in css3 and changes its opacity?*

```css
div{
  float: right;
  display:block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000/ffffff);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```